# How avoid duplication in a list

Tags: c#, random, viewmodel

I'm trying to get a distinct list to my view.I need to select records from a list randomly and put it in to another list.The following code works..But it contain duplication records..How can I overcome this problem?

**Note:** the variable "budget" is a parameter passed in to the controller and "model1" is a List of PlanObjectsViewModel

```
int count = 0;
foreach (var item in model1) { count++; }

List<PlanObjectsViewModel> result = new List<PlanObjectsViewModel>();

Random rand = new Random();
double? temp=0;

while(budget>temp)
{

    int randi = rand.Next(0, count);
    var nthItem = model1.OrderBy(p => p.Id).Skip(randi).First();
    temp += nthItem.Price;

    if (!result.Contains(nthItem)) // Think this is the wrong point
    {
       result.Add(nthItem);
    }


}
```

Comment: have you tried using a hashset ?

Comment: I believe your duplicates are already present on your model1. Contains will only compare class instances unless you explicitly specify equality for your ViewModel, like overriding Equals or providing IEqualityComparer to the Contains method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually you have made it the correct way. For me it looks like you didnt implemented [Equals](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bsc2ak47%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and [GetHashCode](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.gethashcode(v=vs.110).aspx) which are used by List.Contains to compare objects. Well basically GetHashCode is not mandatory but its a good design if you implemented the one to implement the other one.

But ofcourse you can use HashSet as pointed in the other answeres.

Comment: That's the right answer. HashSet would only provide that he wouldn't need to call Contains, but the key to duplication is actually the lack of equality implementation. He could also pass a IEqualityComparer<T> as parameter do Contains instead of overriding Equals, in case he is not allowed to edit that VM code.

Answer (score 4):

Use a `HashSet<PlanObjectsViewModel>`

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
    // Input array that contains three duplicate strings.
    string[] array1 = { "cat", "dog", "cat", "leopard", "tiger", "cat" };

    // Display the array.
    Console.WriteLine(string.Join(",", array1));

    // Use HashSet constructor to ensure unique strings.
    var hash = new HashSet<string>(array1);

    // Convert to array of strings again.
    string[] array2 = hash.ToArray();

    // Display the resulting array.
    Console.WriteLine(string.Join(",", array2));
    }
}
```

Output:

```
cat,dog,cat,leopard,tiger,cat
cat,dog,leopard,tiger
```

Comment: Except that he's dealing with a class that probably doesn't specify equality. HashSet would do him no good, as it would consider equal only objects of the same instance.

Answer (score 2):

there are two ways to do this, use a `hashset` instead of list for your result, or use `Distinct()`

```
HashSet<PlanObjectsViewModel> result
```

or

```
return result.Distinct();
```

You will have have to implement the Equals() method for this to work with objects, a which point your current code should work too.

Comment: Which is almost equivalent since the implementation of Linq's `Distinct` uses a `Set` internally.